# Values From Multi-Row MySQL To Single Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Fetching multi-row data from MySQL database and trying to convert the results into a single array. Since the data is coming from a custom function where modifying it will break many other things, I can't change the way the way it is fetched so must process after retrieval using PHP. This is a sample:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FieldLabel] => 
            [FieldName] => ID
            [FieldValue] => $ID
            [FieldType] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [FieldLabel] => Name
            [FieldName] => Name
            [FieldValue] => $FieldName
            [FieldType] => 1
        )

)
```

Looking for something like this with only all the values in a single array but with the variables populated:

```
Array('','ID',$ID,0,'Name','Name',$FieldName,1)
```

I found this little function in another post that seemed would at lease create the array it but unfortunately it does not and I don't know enough about array manipulation to be able to sort it out. Any ideas?

```
function array2Recursive($array)  {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( array_keys($array) as $k ) :
        $v = $array[$k];
        if (is_scalar($v)) :
            $lst[] = $v;
        elseif (is_array($v)) :
            $lst = array_merge($lst,array2Recursive($v));
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return array_values(array_unique($lst));
}
```

Comment: You said you cant change the way the data is being retrieved. Is this a API or do you have access to the database?

Comment: That array won't work, array keys must be unique. If you wanted to access `FieldType` what would it be `0` or `2`???

Comment: PHP arrays must have unique indexes. Your expected output is not possible, and you're probably looking for something else. It might be more helpful to explain what you want to do with the data.

Comment: The data is being retried through a custom function where changing it will affect many sites that use it. To clarify, I am trying to emulate a manually-created array already in use so that the same function can be used for the data. You're right about the unique indexes as I guess I didn't describe it well. What I am looking for actually is just a single array with only the values and no keys at all so I'll correct the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way to solve this could be to use a foreach to loop through the items and add them to an array:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach($a as $item) {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/S78jq)

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working although it is giving two arrays, one of which contains the full dataset and the other only a partial. I can't tell where it's coming from but still trying to be sure it isn't some leftover code from the earlier tests. Don't see any, though.

Comment: In the code above, the `$item` will be one of the example arrays fro the question for which each value will be added to `$result`. Is your data structure the same as in the demo?

Comment: Thank you again. No, unfortunately I had made a mistake when copy-and-pasting the sample array but I have corrected it in the original question. However, your suggested code seems to be working just fine as it is although if the correct array makes a difference, I am open to trying whatever you suggest.

Comment: Checking further, this is indeed working as needed (the extra array was coming from one of the extra print_r() that had gotten in while testing) although I can't seem to work out how to populate the variables with values at the same time. As a hard-coded array that was being used before, it was easy but coming from the database, not sure how to actually replace $ID and $FieldName with the actual values. However, I suppose that was not part of my original question so I'll either have to create a new posting or try to find a solution.